# In PCB DFM analysis; manufacturer highlighted TOEPRINT ISSUE. What is component TOEPRINT?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

[image: Component TOEPRINT ISSUE]

PCB manufacturer have highlighted component TOEPRINT issue.
Issue Statement: "Component is too close to another component TOEPRINT."

What is mean by TOEPRINT?

Comment: "Toeprints" seems to refer to the pins on an IC.  So, something is too close to one of the pins of that SMD IC.

Answer (score 2):

The footprint is the outline of the component, the toeprint is the pad.

They are saying the component body is too close to the pad for the easiest manufacturing.

Comment: Though I'm sure this is right, it doesn't _look_ too close though...

Comment: @pipe No, it doesn't look like any kind of problem to me.